# How to automatically continue past a one page template in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a form field on a webpage where the user inputs certain information. Simultaneously this information is used to fill out a document below it. I've attached the css I'm using to create the document template. At the moment, if the user inputs a lot of information it will go over one a4 page, however I don't know how to make that show on the webpage, as in I don't know how to make that output automatically continue onto a second page. I'm using js to push text from a user input form into the text field in the a4 page...

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Company Details</title>
    </head>

    <style>fieldset {
    width: 600px;
}


label.field {
    text-align: right;
    width:200px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

input.textbox-300 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

fieldset p {
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
}

    body {
      background: rgb(204,204,204); 
    }

    page {
      background: white;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
        padding: 1;
    }

    page p {
        margin-left: 80;
        margin-right: 80;
    }

    page h1 {
        margin-left: 80;
        margin-right:80;
        margin-top:100;
        margin-bottom:50;
    }

    page[size="A4"] {  
      width: 21cm;
      height: 29.7cm;
    }
    page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
      width: 29.7cm;
      height: 21cm;  
    }

    @media print {
      body, page {
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 0;
      }
    }


</style>

    <body>
        <form action="begin-create-done.html" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <p><label class="field"> Lots of text</label>:
                    <span><input  type="text" name="text1"></span> <br>
            </fieldset>  
        </form>



<page size="A4">
     <h1>
             <span class="text1"></span>
     </h1>
</page>

        <script>
            var formValues = {};
            function inputObj(formNR, defaultValues) { 
                var inputs = formNR.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    formValues[inputs[i].name] = defaultValues[i];
                    if(inputs[i].type === 'text') {
                        inputs[i].value = defaultValues[i];                            
                        outputs = document.getElementsByClassName(inputs[i].name);
                        for ( var j = 0; j < outputs.length; j++) {
                            outputs[j].innerHTML = defaultValues[i];
                        }
                    }
                    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                        formValues[this.name] = this.value;
                        outputs = document.getElementsByClassName(this.name);
                        for ( var j = 0; j < outputs.length; j++) {
                            outputs[j].innerHTML = this.value;
                        }
                    }, false);
                }
            }
                // build a little array with the defaultValues for each input
            var defValues =[];
                // this will push all inputs from the given form in the formValues object.
            inputObj(document.forms[0], defValues); 
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the JavaScript code that pushes form content over to the page?  This isn't a CSS issue.

Comment: as @zipzit mentioned, this (if even possible) sounds way too complicated to do with CSS. Javascript would be simpler.

Comment: Hi ziptit and Obed, thanks for responding, I didn't realise I should use JavaScript (new to this). Lemme have a go and come back. Thanks.

Comment: Then how is the information copied over from the input fields to the document? What kind of framework or library are you using?

Comment: Hi @Mr Lister see link pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046522/class-name-instead-of-id-for-live-output

Comment: @TopGangMember Ah, so you _are_ using Javascript. Can you put that information into the question here? This question needs to be self-contained; we shouldn't have to flip back and forth between pages to get the whole picture.

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, I wasn't using javascript to push text across different pages that's why I didn't think it relevant, but I've now updated the question to include it. Thanks.